# AngularJS filter by array in array

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

I have an array as such:

```
$scope.posts = [
  {"from":"Aaron", "groups":[1,2,3]},
  {"from":"Byron", "groups":[1,2,4]},
  {"from":"Caren", "groups":[1,3,5]}
]
```

I am trying to filter by group in Controller. So for example, if I only want posts where groups contain `2`, it would show only Aaron and Byron posts.

I tried doing this with a button `ng-click` function:

```
<button ng-click="filterByGroup(2)">Filter</button>
```

And in controller,

```
.controller ('Ctrl',$scope, $filter) {

    $scope.posts = [
      {"from":"Aaron", "groups":[1,2,3]},
      {"from":"Byron", "groups":[1,2,4]},
      {"from":"Caren", "groups":[1,3,5]}
    ];

    $scope.filterByGroup = function (group_no){
       $filter('filter')($scope.posts,?,group_no)
    }
}
```

I know I can do a function in the ?, but I am not sure how to do so. Was thinking of doing `indexOf` but I can't do `groups.IndexOf(group_no)`.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: solution is to actually create a filter function that does use `indexOf()` on groups property. Note that `$filter` doesn't do anything without assigning the return value

Comment: Ah....yes. i understand now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just do

```
  <div ng-repeat="post in posts | filter: { groups: 2 } : true">
    {{ post.from }}
  </div>
```

---

Fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/0fqavhbu/

Comment: I can't do in HTML as I already have a filter by input text hooked up for it. Hmm, i think i can do a function (item) {return item.groups.indexOf(group_id)};  thingie. On my mobile right now, will try later.